# React native gradle build fail : "node -e console.log(require('react-native/cli').bin);" : command fail

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I try to run my React Native app in an android emulator on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 installation.

In Android studio, gradle build failed with this error :

```
[org.gradle.api.Script] :ReactNative:Running '[node, -e, console.log(require('react-native/cli').bin);'] command failed.

[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Where:
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Script '/home/melvine/DevProjects/production/evener/mobile/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle' line: 179
```

However, when I run the following command in the project folder, it runs successfully.

```
$ node -e "console.log(require('react-native/cli').bin);"

/home/melvine/DevProjects/production/evener/mobile/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/bin.js
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: Which react-native version are you on

Comment: @EL173 I'm using `"react-native": "0.62.2"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I have installed NodeJS using nvm but (I don't know why) Gradle can't execute it. So I installed node with apt-get and now everything work well.